# Android JUnitRunner Empty Test Suite: No Test Results

Tags: android, junit, junit4, android-testing

I'm having trouble running tests in Android Studio. I've read through a load of posts with the same problem here on Stack Overflow, but to no avail. Just to be clear, I want to test in the emulator and not in the JVM.

Run configuration:

[image: run-config]

Output:

```
Running tests
Test running startedTest running failed: No test results
Empty test suite.
```

Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ntnu.stud.markul.crowdshelf"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    // Unit testing dependencies
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:rules:0.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.3') {
        // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since the test runner
        // hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The test class (located in /src/androidTest/java/com/appname/app/):

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class NetworkAndDBInstrumentationTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {
    private MainActivity mActivity;
    public NetworkAndDBInstrumentationTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        // Injecting the Instrumentation instance is required
        // for your test to run with AndroidJUnitRunner.
        injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        mActivity = getActivity();
    }

    @Test
    public void typeOperandsAndPerformAddOperation() {
        NetworkController.getCrowd("55f01f29f0a5fad2120bb1db");
        System.out.print("ok");
        Log.d("1TEST", "1TEST");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use the new com.android.support.test:rules:0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work using this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class NetworkAndDBInstrumentationTest {
    //use the following annotation and declare an ActivityTestRule for your activity under test
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<RealmActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule(RealmActivity.class);

    //use @Before to setup your test fixture
    @Before
    public void setUp() {  }

    //annotate all test methods with
    @Test
    public void testGetCrowd() {
        Assert.assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
    @After
    public void tearDown() {  }
}
```

Where RealmActivity is the Activity I want to test. Build.gradle and everything else is as in the question post. Now, a follow-up question: What does it matter that I make the @Rule with RealmActivity? Can't I use other Activities in that test? Can I make a Activity-independent test?

Comment: hi, i am facing the same issue and i am using gradle 1.2.3 and studio 1.2.1 and the gradle that gets downloaded is 2.5. But this does not work still.The  emulator i am working on is having android api level 10. What am i missing? Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks right. You can try to add this to your build.gradle file:

```
/*
 * Working build.gradle test config. Gradle version 1.3.0
 */


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "test.your.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode versionMajor * 100 + versionMinor * 10 + versionPatch
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
    }

    configurations.all {
        // Currently espresso is dependent on support-annotations:22.2.1
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'SetJavaScriptEnabled'
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        abortOnError false
        textReport true
        textOutput 'stdout'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }

        release {
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            versionName "DEV"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {  //this one may not be needed. But wont hurt.
        androidTest.setRoot('src/androidTest')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Android
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'

    // Google Play Services
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:7.8.0'

    // Integration Tests
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2'
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2') {
        exclude group:'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }

    // Unit Tests
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'com.google.truth:truth:0.25'

    //Mocking
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:${DEXMAKER_VERSION}"
    androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:${DEXMAKER_VERSION}"
    androidTestApt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${DAGGER_VERSION}"

    // Set this dependency to use JUnit 4 rules
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'

    // Leak detection
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
}
```

You could also try using JUnit 3 style to see if that gets better results. Are you extending ApplicationTestCase? Try and get things working there.

Comment: If I add `sourceSets` or `configurations.all` to build.gradle I get the message (from hovering in android studio): "Method call is ambiguous. This inspection reports assignments with incompatible types". I can't build it: Error:(65, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'setRoot()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'android' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.

Comment: I get the same warning, but my config works :) This stuff is extremely difficult to get going. I failed A LOT of times.

Comment: I edited the post: I can't build it: http://s24.postimg.org/9eykvij91/Untitled.png

Comment: What's your gradle version? The code I'm looking at is running 1.2.3. Have you looked at these: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing ?

Comment: I updated my answer with a working test config's build.gradle file for gradle version 1.3.0 (classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0' in the top level build.gradle).

Comment: Testing on android emulator is horrible. Even the official documentation is outdated or contradictory. Should I extend ApplicationTestCase, ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 or none?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need add this line in your dependencies:

```
androidTestCompile ('org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3')
```

Comment: Why is this the solution?